# Print json object from local storage

Tags: javascript, json

i need to print an array of json object which are been entered by user through text box, this function is executed by button click. i need to store all the string localy that are entered by the user in text box. and display it in my console in this formate `[{"aaa"},{"bbb"},{"ccc"}]`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    Enter the string :
    <input type="text" id="names">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Click Me</button>

    <script>
    function myFunction(){
      var myNames = new Array();
      myNames = document.getElementById("names").value;
      this.names = myNames; 

      localStorage["myNames"] = JSON.stringify(myNames);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myNames));

      var name = JSON.parse(localStorage["myNames"]);
      console.log(name);
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently this code just print the data like this `"aaa"`, if i add another data `bbb`, only the 2nd data `"bbb"`is displayed. i want all the data to be viewed in this formate `[{"aaa"},{"bbb"},{"ccc"}]` or even like this [{"name":"aaa"},{"name":"bbb"},{"name":"ccc"}] . 
Could someone help me?

Comment: Remark: It's always better to have your script just before the closing `</body>`.

Comment: @Cohars — That isn't true. There are circumstances when it is better to have it in the head.

Comment: Also note that `[{"aaa"},{"bbb"},{"ccc"}]` is not valid JSON. @Quentin, yes, most of the time it save you from some mistakes. Here it's ok because `document.getElementById("names")` is in a function. I should be outside though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
    var myNames = []

    function myFunction(){
        var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myNames')) || [];

         newItem = {"name":document.getElementById("names").value};
         oldItems.push(newItem);

        localStorage.setItem("myNames", JSON.stringify(oldItems));

        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myNames")));
    };
```

Comment: i am getting like this ["", "dd", "ddd", "gg", "ggg"]  is there any possiablity to get like this [{"aaa"},{"bbb"},{"ccc"}] or [{"name":"aaa"},{"name":"bbb"},{"name":"ccc"}]

Answer (score 4):

That's not related to localStorage or JSON.
When you perform `myNames = document.getElementById("names").value;` you replace the empty Array with a string.

You may use .push on array : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

And create an object then pushing it, for example `myObj = {'v': value}; myArray.push(myObj);`

Comment: The above sample works fine, could give some link to learn in detail about JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the previously entered data, you have to retrieve them first and alter them.

Below are two functions; one that adds an item to the array. If the array isn't present yet (so no data has been entered previously), it creates a new array for you.

Afterwards it stores the data in the localStorage again.

Upon entering new data that needs to be added, it first retrieves any previous entries and alters that. Then it stores again and so on and so on.

```
function myFunction(){
  var myNames = localStorage.getItem('myNames'),
        parsedArray = JSON.parse(myNames),
        valueToAdd = document.getElementById("names").value;

  // Add the new item to the original array.
  parsedArray = addToArray(parsedArray, valueToAdd);
  localStorage.setItem('myNames', JSON.stringify(parsedArray));

  console.log(parsedArray);
};

function addToArray (array, item) {
  // If the array doesn't exist, create one
  if (!array) {
    array = [];
  }

  // Add the item to the array.
  array.push(item);

  return array;
};
```

Comment: i am getting error 4 Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.get is not a functionmyFunction @ jsontest.html:14onclick @ jsontest.html:80

Comment: My bad, that should've been localStorage.getItem